# Split each element of an IEnumerable list using MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to split each item of an IEnumerable list by any existing chars (/ , ;) and I am not sure how to approach this problem. The purpose of this function is to get all the existing plots, split them by the extra chars, display unique plot numbers on screen only and tick as appropiate. At the moment my function only displays the correct list of plots and I am not sure were to Split(',') them. This is my function:

```
public ActionResult CopyPlotsCSR(int id)
    {
        var CSR = db.CSRs.Find(id);
        Quote oldQuote = CSR.OrderOld.Quote;
        var qp = db.QuoteProducts.Where(q => q.QuoteID == oldQuote.ID && q.Revision == oldQuote.Revision && q.Plot != null).OrderBy(q => q.Plot);
        var plots = qp.Select(j => j.Plot).Distinct();
        List<PlotSelector> Plots = new List<PlotSelector>();
        foreach (var item in plots)
        {
            Plots.Add(new PlotSelector() { Plot = item });
        }
        ViewBag.CSRID = id;
        return View(Plots.ToList());
    }
```

This is my model:

```
public class PlotSelector
{
    public PlotSelector() { this.Select = false; }

    public PlotSelector(QuoteProduct qp)
    {
        this.QuoteProduct = qp;
        this.QuoteProductID = qp.ID;
        this.Plot = qp.Plot;
        this.Select = false;
    }

    public virtual QuoteProduct QuoteProduct { get; set; }
    public long QuoteProductID { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public bool Select { get; set; }
}
```

}

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ERP.ViewModels.PlotSelector>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Quote";
ViewBag.SubTitle = "Create";
}

<h2>Create New Quote based on Plots</h2>

@Html.ActionImage("Edit", "CSR", new { id = ViewBag.CSRID }, "~/Content/Images/BackToCSR.png", "Back To CSR")

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Confirm
        </th>
        <th>
            Plot
        </th>
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</table>
```

This is my EditorForModel() view:

```
@model ERP.ViewModels.PlotSelector
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Select)
        @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.QuoteProductID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.Plot)
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my current output:

```
[CheckBox]   586, 587, 588, 589
[CheckBox]   21, 22, 25
[CheckBox]   3, 65, 68
[CheckBox]   21, 68, 586
```

I need an output like the following:

```
[CheckBox]   3
[CheckBox]   21
[CheckBox]   22
[CheckBox]   25
[CheckBox]   65
[CheckBox]   68
[CheckBox]   586
[CheckBox]   587
[CheckBox]   588
[CheckBox]   589
```

Any help/hints would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
@model ERP.ViewModels.PlotSelector

@{
   var temp = Model.Plot.Split(',');

}

@foreach(var item in temp)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Select)
        @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.QuoteProductID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(item)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that but my output is showing me only empty spaces for the Plot column. I do have more rows now but I do not see any values on each row.

Comment: you have comma seperated plots in `Plot` property? also see edit i mistakenly put double quotes in `Split()` instead of single

Comment: I've noticed the (","). Regarding the Plot property do you mean how the plots are saved? In that case an example would be: 2,3,7,14,24,46,47,49,64,65. Rest of my code is up. Not sure what to do.

Comment: That @Html.Display(item) is not showing me anything atm.

Comment: replace it with just: ``<td>
        @item
    </td>`` and check

Comment: in ever used ``Display()`` this way but it should work logically

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
foreach (var item in plots)
        {
      var subplots = item.Split(new char[] { ';', ',' , '/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(var sub in subplots) {

                Plots.Add(new PlotSelector() { Plot = sub });
        }
        }
```

I have not tested the code but what I understand that you are getting values in item variable with ; , / special characters and you would want to split before you insert into plots list for view consumption.

In that case, you should split when the value is inserted into the list.

That is exactly what the above code is doing for you.

Otherwise, you can also move the split statement into your view level as well and then loop through in foreach....

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. Would like to mention I've replaced "tests" with "item" and made it work.